# Short story about a trial

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Name of a short story (maybe in *Dangerous Visions*?) about a man on trial who is ultimately shot with a crossbow to the words "I will have committed no crime".  The accused's name is Melifluens or something similar.

Answer (score 11):

This is the story "[In the Matter of the Assassin Merefirs](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51190)" by Ken W. Purdy. It is a duplicate of [Looking for a short story where shooting a man with a crossbow is not legally prohibited](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139341/looking-for-a-short-story-where-shooting-a-man-with-a-crossbow-is-not-legally-pr).

The accused is called *Merefirs* not *Melifluens*. He is an assassin who has killed someone with a crossbow, and his defence is that this is not a crime. The judge agrees and orders a court official to shoot Merefirs with a crossbow saying:

> "Stand across the room," the judge says, "and let us see if you can strike the assassin Merefirs in the middle of his chest. Have no fear. As Terravan has so convincingly proved to us, you will be committing no crime."